# How can i search from mongodb with onchange input field?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, fetch

I am building a warehouse website .In my website i displayed a input field and a search button. By this search button I want to search all the product which includes only my search property not the whole thing. But in mogodb, i can't do this. Because in Mongodb i have to write the whole search property for this.
Example : In DB i have an property {name:Jhon Doe, email:jhon00@gmail.com}
If my search value (Jhon) it will give me this property, But in mongodb i have to search by full name like (Jhon Doe).How can i solve the problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to to write the whole search property in mongoDb ,
just use regex like this :

```js
const reg  = new RegExp(inputSearch);
const preson = await Person.findOne({ "name" : { $regex: reg, $options: 'gi' } },
```

i hope this helped you .
Good luck